# IE9 Images expanding outside of containing div

Tags: explorer

(first post on stack overflow!)
Computer Engineer, but I'm fairly new to web development and I'm trying to learn all the best practices.

I typically add my styling class to a div when adding an image. (not so sure this is the best way anymore)

So for example, right now I'm adding a div with a border and a max width/height of 100% then letting the image inside the div expand to either but not outside of the div.

This however isn't working in IE9. Its expanding the to image full size creating major layout issues.

This has probably been gone over but I couldn't seem to get the search terms right to find the answer.

So is there a standard way to fix this? Even though it won't really be too difficult to add max-width and max-height to the  tag I don't really wan't to do that..I'm sure there will be some issues with doing that. This site I've been working on is getting fairly large and VERY complex.

I think internet explorer might be a tiny bit retarded. How did it ever become a major browser!? Go Chrome!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example of your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4vdCB/

This is roughly what I've been doing. It actually gives me the result I get in explorer on the fiddle. However, in chrome, on my actual site it works exactly as I need it to. The picture is centered within a div that is 168px by 168px.

I'm guessing the way to fix it is to just apply some styling to the actual image itself. Anyone know why this works in chrome / firefox?